# How to create Angular Universal Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile, containers, angular-universal

So I am trying to Dockerize my Angular universal app to use it with already dockerized spring boot rest backend and I find hard times to get some help and resources on the internet. Here I have an example of Dockerfile of Angular universal but it doesn't work for me despite the changes I do.

```
FROM node:12-alpine as buildContainer
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build:universal
# RUN npm run generate:pretender
RUN npm run test:ssr

FROM node:8-alpine

WORKDIR /app
# Copy dependency definitions
COPY --from=buildContainer /app/package.json /app
# COPY --from=buildContainer /app/server.js /app

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY --from=buildContainer /app/dist /app/dist
# COPY --from=buildContainer /app/static /app/static
COPY --from=buildContainer /app/dist-server /app/dist-server

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 4200

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "run", "server"]
```

I'm building the image with following command `docker build -t angular-universal .` but it fails in 6th step saying

**npm ERR! missing script: build:universal
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-19T20_29_16_368Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build:universal' returned a non-zero code: 1**

Does anyone had the same problem ?

Here is my package.json

```
{
"name": "jobnow",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "deploy": "ng deploy --base-href=https://samgevorgyan.github.io/jobnow/"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^1.5.0",
    "@capacitor/angular": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "latest",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@gilsdav/ngx-translate-router": "^3.0.0",
    "@gilsdav/ngx-translate-router-http-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.3",
    "angular-cli-ghpages": "^0.6.2",
    "crypto-ts": "^1.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.1.6",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "latest",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~13.7.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.6.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you run the same `npm` command outside Docker in your local development setup?  Can you include more of the error log?

Comment: And add your package.json please

Comment: my local development setup works more or less good, after each time I do npm install it says "do npm audit fix", but the application bootstraps and communicates with backend services properly. I think I am missing "scripts":{} definition in the package.json that's why "universal" doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

May be a little late but in your Dockerfile:

> RUN npm run build:universal

You need to have a script in your package.json like this:

```
"build:universal": "ng build --prod && ng run jobnow:server:production"
```

There is also this line:

> RUN npm run test:ssr

You can remove  it or add another script like this:

```
"test:ssr": "run-p test:ssr:*"
```